# Remove the function in a cell and save as

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel files, there is a function in cell A1 of each sheet. How do I remove this function but still keep the value of cell A1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA it's very simple

```
Range("A1").Value = Range("A1").Value
```

Might need to qualify the sheet if you're calling it from a module etc.

```
Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").Value
```

If you're doing this on a grand scale and you're not using currency or date types, you can use `.Value2` to speed things up.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value2

```
Range("A1").Value2 = Range("A1").Value2
```

Comment: thanks. ".Value" works. For some reason, ".Value2 does not work. it might as well be because I changed something prior.

Comment: That is weird. I use it often with no issues, but there will be a reason for you. As long you're not suffering because of it we can ignore it for now!